# understand how to combine `contains` `upper` method within in a `if then else` statement for new variable creation using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which i want to create a new column that combines other columns values.
 (i write it using a if then statement just to show what i like to obtain):

```
if upper([Url]) cointains 'A' THEN "AAA"
ELSE IF (upper([Url]) cointains 'B' AND upper([Url]) NOT cointains 'Z') THEN "BBB"
ELSE IF  (upper([Url]) cointains 'B' AND upper([Url]) cointains 'Z') THEN "CCC"
ELSE UPPER(VAR_NAME)
END AS NEW_VAR
```

is it possible using pandas?
What i expect is to understand how to combine `contains` `upper` method within in a `if then else` statement for new variable creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) together with [`.str` accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html):

```
df['NEW_VAR'] = np.select( 
        [df.Url.str.upper().str.contains('A'),
         df.Url.str.upper().str.contains('B') & ~df.Url.str.upper().str.contains('Z'),
         df.Url.str.upper().str.contains('B') & df.Url.str.upper().str.contains('Z')],    
         ['AAA', 'BBB', 'ZZZ'],  
         df.Url.str.upper())
```

With `df = pd.DataFrame({'Url': ['a', 'bb', 'bz', 'c']})` you get:

```
  Url NEW_VAR
0   a     AAA
1  bb     BBB
2  bz     ZZZ
3   c       C
```

Comment: thx i did it but i get a key error: **KeyError: None of [Index([list of my df elements]  are in the [columns]** and it did not create the columns

Comment: what is the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: all my df columns, included Url columns that i use for compute the code, but not the new column 'NEW_VAR'

Comment: strange, if you have a column with the name `'Url'` then I don't understand the problem. It's obviously unrelated to this question. See my working example data in the answer.